# What does the "EE - M" switch do on a Vivitar lens with TX mount for Canon FD?

Tags: lens-adapter, vivitar

I have a Vivitar zoom lens with a TX adapter for Canon FD.  On the adapter is a slide switch marked "EE - M".

What is the function of the switch?

Comment: Can you upload a photo?

Comment: This is the link to an ebay post that shows the mount.  The last photo in the post shows the EE - M switch.  If you go to ebay, search vivitar tx mount canon fd.  If you can't view the post, let me know and I will get a photo and send it.  Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 4):

According to [this picture of an instruction manual](https://www.flickr.com/photos/gperis/46687559824),

[image]

this would be a switch between auto and manual modes (to be used in conjunction with the aperture ring on the lens). Is there a green circle on the aperture ring of your lens?